# Relations Laravel 4 from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel-4

i'm starting to learn laravel 4 but i'm still far, I already took a look ORM and relations so i have the following question:

I have 3 type of table: users, posts, content_post and i would like have the ralations having like result all the posts and contents about a user.

users table

```
id | userame | name |
 1    Ellie    Elen
 2    Pol      Paul
```

posts table

```
id | id_poster |
 1      1
 2      1
 3      2
```

content_post

```
id | id_post | text | link | video | photo
 1      1      hey    NULL   NULL    tree.png
 2      2      woo    http   NULL    NULL
 3      3      Hi     NULL   NULL    NULL
```

php

```
    class User Extends Eloquent {

     function posts() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('posts','id_poster');
     }

    }

    class Posts Extends Eloquent {

     function user() {
         return $this->HasOne('users');
     }

     function content() {
       return $this->HasOne('content_post','id_post');
     }

    }

  class Content Extends Eloquent {

     function posts() {
         return $this->HasOne('posts');
     }

  }

    ?>
```

and then i'll go to get the results like so but it doesn't show me nothing

```
$user = new User;
$user = $user->find(1)->posts();
```

Where i'm doing error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare relations in this way:

```
class User Extends Eloquent {

    function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('Posts','id_poster'); /* Note that 'Posts' is model name - not table */
    }

}

class Posts Extends Eloquent {

    function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id_poster');
    }

    function content() {
        return $this->hasOne('Content','id_post');
    }

}

class Content Extends Eloquent {

   function posts() {
       return $this->belongsTo('Posts', 'id_post');
   }
}
```

After you can try to request user with posts:

```
$user = new User();
$user = $user->with('posts.content')->find(1);
```

Comment: Also it would be much easier if you will stick to some rules like using singular names for models (User, Post, Content).

Comment: thnx for the reply, you has been clear. But when i try to a foreach for show the results it show me Trying to get property of non-object what can be the problem?#

Comment: Probably you are trying to iterate Builder object. Note that $user->posts() does not return collection. In order to iterate through the user related posts you can access them via magic method __get(). Something like: foreach($user->posts as $post){}

Comment: Ok! Thank you! Sorry for this stupid question, but why $user->posts() does not return collection even if we had set the relations?

Comment: Mainly because it used for query building purposes. Builder object allows you to implement more sophisticated logic (filtration, sorting etc.). For instance you can write this way: $user->posts()->where('created_at', '<', $timestamp)->get();